# How to wait / check if elements exist

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering is there a way for me to check if element exist then do a function then repeat but with next id.

example: if log2643673 exist do function then check or wait for log2643674 exist and if exist then do function

if it dose not exist keep checking into it exist and do function and then find next element exist

```js
var checkExist = setInterval(function() {
   if ($('#log2643673').length) {
      console.log("it exists!");
   }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li id="log2643670" data-log="2643670" class="logs">Text here</li>

<li id="log2643671" data-log="2643671" class="logs">Text here</li>

<li id="log2643672" data-log="2643672" class="logs">Text here</li>

<li id="log2643673" data-log="2643673" class="logs">Text here</li>
```

sorry for my bad english

Comment: I've added an answer.

Comment: How do you figure out "the next id"? Do you have a list of IDs? Are they always in order?

Comment: do you know the maximum amount of elements you are expecting?

Comment: @Mark Meyer no i do not have a list of id's and yes they load in order

Comment: @Nico the maximum amount of elements i'm expecting is endless

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an "exists" function for jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044/is-there-an-exists-function-for-jquery)

Comment: you can get  lists of ids by iterate over  ** $('li') **.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$(function() {
    var logIdStart = 2643670; // the start log id
    // timer to check if element exists
    var checkExist = setInterval(function() {
       if ($("#log" + logIdStart ).length) {
          console.log("it exists!");
          logIdStart++; // update id only if element is found             
       }
    }, 1000 /* change checking frequency if needed*/ );

});
```

Play here

```js
$(function() {
    var logIdStart = 2643670; // the start log id
    $('button').on('click',function(){   
     $("body").append('<li id="log'+logIdStart+'">log'+logIdStart+'</li>');
    
    });
    // timer to check if element exists
    var checkExist = setInterval(function() {
       if ($("#log" + logIdStart ).length) {
          $("body").append("log" + logIdStart + " exists!<br />");
          logIdStart++;
       }
    }, 1000 /* change checking frequency if needed*/ );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="log2643670" data-log="2643670" class="logs">Text here</li>

<li id="log2643671" data-log="2643671" class="logs">Text here</li>

<li id="log2643672" data-log="2643672" class="logs">Text here</li>

<li id="log2643673" data-log="2643673" class="logs">Text here</li>
<div>
<button>Add Input</button>
</div>
```

Comment: logical issue in your code [kiranvj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1188322/kiranvj).

Comment: 1) when element added in DOM it will not update variables in your example **$logElement**.
2) **logIdStart ** is not incrementing, it just adding 1 on 2643670 every time on this line **$logElement = $("#log" + (logIdStart + 1))**.

Comment: @shajji I didnt get it, you mean `$logElement = $("#log" + (logIdStart + 1))` not working?

Comment: i mean it always get same element because $("#log" + (2643670 + 1)), everytime 1 added to 2643670, executing this line 1000 times always give u $('#log2643671'), sorry for english

Comment: @shajji it will reflect as long as the start element id is `"log" + logIdStart`, because we are checking it in every 1 sec

Comment: check this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/yj40hrgb/), i guess u did it by mistake, your **$logElement = $("#log" + logIdStart );** inside the if condtion. u should place outside the if condtion

Comment: @shajji it should work as we are checking `$logElement.length` everytime inside the timer. Check this example https://jsfiddle.net/1pgekc8s/4/

Comment: what will happened when element dynamically added ? https://jsfiddle.net/1pgekc8s/17/

Comment: @shajji I got your point here, I have updated the answer. You should have added the answer, you deserve the credits. :)

Comment: thnx :) @Kiranvj

Answer (score 0):

Evaluate if the length of the element is greater than cero.

```
var string_part = '#log';
var initial_number = 2643670;
var checkExist = setInterval(function() {
   var element = $(string_part + initial_number);
   if (element.length > 0) {
      console.log("it exists!");
      initial_number ++;
   }
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you have random IDs and need to check element is exists or not then you can do this :

```js
$(function() {

    var myListOfIds=$('li');   //Hold all the li tags.    
    var cnt=0;  // we will use it in array iterate.
     
    // timer to check if element exists
    var checkExistInterval = setInterval(function() {
        if(cnt== (myListOfIds.length)){
          console.log(" Yeah, clear the interval,we have done it :)")
          clearInterval(checkExistInterval);
        }         
        else if ($("#" + myListOfIds[cnt].id ).length) {
              console.log(myListOfIds[cnt].id +" Yes, I am in...");
              cnt++; 
        } 
    }, 1000 /* Lets change checking frequency if needed*/ );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="log2643670" data-log="2643670" class="logs">Text here</li>

<li id="log2643671" data-log="2643671" class="logs">Text here</li>

<li id="log2643672" data-log="2643672" class="logs">Text here</li>

<li id="log2643673" data-log="2643673" class="logs">Text here</li>

<li id="IAmRandom" data-log="2643673" class="logs">Text here</li>
<div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you know the starting id of your elements which you are trying to find and they come in numeric order.

You can use pure Javascript to do this

```
let counter = 2643670;
let checkExist = setInterval(function() {
   const id = 'log' + counter;
   const element = document.getElementById(id);
   if (!!element) {
      // Do you function call here
      counter++;
   }
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

There you go. :)

```
 function checkExist(startID) {
     setInterval(() => {
       if (document.getElementById(startID)) {
         console.log(`ID ${startID++} exists`);
       }
     } ,1000)
 }
```